# Need a newer version of Pcre.dll on Windows XP

Tags: dll

I am trying to install a program on Windows XP, but get the following error:

> The procedure pcre_dfa_exec could not be located in the DLL pcre.dll

I guess that my pcre.dll file is outdated. I keep downloading pcre.dll from different sites,
with the same result. Could someone point me to where I can download the needed version?

I only see source files on the Internet, but they require "compilation" (is that the right word? ) and is beyond my capability.

Comment: Might help if you tell us what program you are attempting to install.

Comment: What is the date of the pcre.dll file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the `pcre-7.0-bin.zip` from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/pcre/7.0/

Then unzip it somewhere and inside you'll find a folder called `bin`, open it and rename the `pcre3.dll` to just `pcre.dll`.

That might work, and if not try downloading(older versions where it says just `pcre.dll` inside the `bin` folder or `pcre2.dll`).

Comment: Thanks Shedokan and Amazed, your link worked! With pcre3.dll the former warning disappeared, but now I am getting the next warning:

"The procedure pcre_free_ex could not be located in the DLL pcre.dll"

I looked at pcre-8.0-bin package, but files in it are strange. I renamed and tried one, and it was not recognized by Windows.

Comment: It could be that it just didn't get to that error :) so a newer version could have even more errors than the one you had. That is why you should tell us the date of the program and the date of the dll you had(creation date) that way we'll be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows port of the Perl Compatible Regular Expression library can be downloaded from its SourceForge page, part of the GNUWin32 project: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pcre.htm